# Build issues for apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have been having a sbt dependency issue when I try to build my apache spark project. I have Apache Spark 1.3.1.

My .sbt file is this:

```
name := "Transaction"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
"Spray Repository" at "http://repo.spray.cc/")
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.3.1: not found
```

I have looked all over and this seems to be a persistent issue, but no one has really solved it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. You just need to put `"provided"`after the spark version.

```
name := "Transaction Fraud"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided"

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
"Spray Repository" at "http://repo.spray.cc/")
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
“org.apache.spark” % “spark-core_2.10” % “1.3.1”
```

instead of

```
“org.apache.spark” %% “spark-core” % “1.3.1”
```

and it worked!

EDIT:
However, I was able to get the latter statement to work after specifically making my scalaVersion 2.10 so:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10"
```

Probably because it tries to look for a specific 2.10.4 jar which doesn't exist.